# Why am I able to perform TCP handshake only from one side?

Tags: linux, tcp, netcat, handshake

From my 2 laptops on LAN (one is 10.0.0.11 and the other is 10.0.0.15). From one laptop, I could create passive connection via listening and everything works fine, the other laptop `ACK` the communication. But I cannot do the same the other way - making passive listener from the other laptop:

LAP1 = laptop(10.0.0.11), LAP2 = laptop(10.0.0.15)

*LAP1*

```
$ tcpdump -i wlp2s0 -t -n src 10.0.0.15 or src 10.0.0.11 > output &
$ nc -nl 4444
hello
hi
^C
```

*LAP2*

```
$nc -n 10.0.0.11 4444
hello
hi
^C
```

Now everything works and the *output* is:

```
IP 10.0.0.15.35410 > 10.0.0.11.4444: Flags [S], seq 3649576842, win 64240, options [mss 1460,sackOK,TS val 1557903826 ecr 0,nop,wscale 7], length 0
IP 10.0.0.11.4444 > 10.0.0.15.35410: Flags [S.], seq 2552044612, ack 3649576843, win 65160, options [mss 1460,sackOK,TS val 2837963760 ecr 1557903826,nop,wscale 7], length 0
IP 10.0.0.11.4444 > 10.0.0.15.35410: Flags [S.], seq 2552044612, ack 3649576843, win 65160, options [mss 1460,sackOK,TS val 2837964778 ecr 1557903826,nop,wscale 7], length 0
IP 10.0.0.11.4444 > 10.0.0.15.35410: Flags [S.], seq 2552044612, ack 3649576843, win 65160, options [mss 1460,sackOK,TS val 2837966794 ecr 1557903826,nop,wscale 7], length 0
IP 10.0.0.15.35410 > 10.0.0.11.4444: Flags [.], ack 1, win 502, options [nop,nop,TS val 1557907412 ecr 2837963760], length 0
IP 10.0.0.11.4444 > 10.0.0.15.35410: Flags [P.], seq 1:7, ack 1, win 510, options [nop,nop,TS val 2837966936 ecr 1557907412], length 6
IP 10.0.0.15.35410 > 10.0.0.11.4444: Flags [.], ack 7, win 502, options [nop,nop,TS val 1557907421 ecr 2837966936], length 0
IP 10.0.0.15.35410 > 10.0.0.11.4444: Flags [P.], seq 1:4, ack 7, win 502, options [nop,nop,TS val 1557908702 ecr 2837966936], length 3
IP 10.0.0.11.4444 > 10.0.0.15.35410: Flags [.], ack 4, win 510, options [nop,nop,TS val 2837968227 ecr 1557908702], length 0
IP 10.0.0.11.4444 > 10.0.0.15.35410: Flags [F.], seq 7, ack 4, win 510, options [nop,nop,TS val 2837971235 ecr 1557908702], length 0
IP 10.0.0.15.35410 > 10.0.0.11.4444: Flags [F.], seq 4, ack 8, win 502, options [nop,nop,TS val 1557911933 ecr 2837971235], length 0
IP 10.0.0.11.4444 > 10.0.0.15.35410: Flags [.], ack 5, win 510, options [nop,nop,TS val 2837971644 ecr 1557911933], length 0
```

So far so good.

But If I try to initiate the other way around:

*LAP2*:

```
$nc -nl 4444
```

*LAP1*:

```
$ tcpdump -i wlp2s0 -t -n src 10.0.0.15 or src 10.0.0.11 > output2 &
$nc -n 10.0.0.15 4444
```

I do not even get connection, the `10.0.0.11` (LAP1) is only trying to send `SEQ` many times but the other side do not respond and thus the handshake is not complete:

output of `output2`:

```
IP 10.0.0.11.47928 > 10.0.0.15.4444: Flags [S], seq 2268838313, win 64240, options [mss 1460,sackOK,TS val 2837899323 ecr 0,nop,wscale 7], length 0
IP 10.0.0.11.47928 > 10.0.0.15.4444: Flags [S], seq 2268838313, win 64240, options [mss 1460,sackOK,TS val 2837900330 ecr 0,nop,wscale 7], length 0
IP 10.0.0.11.47928 > 10.0.0.15.4444: Flags [S], seq 2268838313, win 64240, options [mss 1460,sackOK,TS val 2837902346 ecr 0,nop,wscale 7], length 0
...
```

As you can see the other side (10.0.0.15) do not respond if it is passive connection. Were it active one (not listening, just connecting) as in previous case, there is no problem. But if it is listening, it is not responding. What could cause that? How to solve this one-direction connection? Why it connect if active but not if passive?

Comment: Probably a firewall problem.

Comment: Check your firewall on LAP2 and make sure it allows incoming connections to port 4444.

Comment: @Barmar what can I do to examine the issue? (find the real root of cause, whether it is firewall or something else)

Comment: @Barmar it must be allowing port 4444, otherwise the active connection would not be successful, but it was. Only pasive connection is not working

Comment: Active connection has outgoing port 4444, incoming goes to an ephemeral port.